# Dual of a dual graph is not itself?

Tags: graph-theory

Consider the graph $G$

[image]

I made the dual of $G$ and then I made the dual of that graph and I'm not getting $G$....

Is it only true for connected graphs?

How do we calculate the rank of a dual graph if $G$ is disconnected?

Comment: I think the dual is always connected, so a non-connected graph csnnot be the dual of its dual.

Comment: Then will the rank of the dual of $G$ be f - 1 = 3 - 1 = 2?

Comment: Yes, I think so. But please bear in mind that I know literally nothing about graphs. I'm mostly reading the definitions.

Comment: @numberphile: The **plane** dual of a plane graph is defined if and only if the plane graph is connected. If the plane graph is not connected, you can form an **abstract** dual. Look up theses notions in some textbooks about graph theory. It is worth your effort.

Answer (score 1):

The dual $G^*$ of a non-connected planar graph $G=(V,E)$ is commonly defined to be the union of the duals of each connected component of $G$. This way $(G^*)^*=G$ and for an edge set $A \subseteq E$ we have $r_{G^*}(A)=|A|-r_G(E)+r_G(E-A)$.